# What is going on with 'marker' and 'infoWindow' instances in the code below?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am a javascript noob, but I'm most familiar with Java. What I don't understand is why the instances are not written like

```
var marker = new Marker({
                position:props.coords,
                map:map,
                //icon:props.iconImage  
                });
```

instead of

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:props.coords,
            map:map,
            //icon:props.iconImage  
            });
```

and

```
var infoWindow = new InfoWindow({
                    content:props.content

                });
```

instead of

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content:props.content

                });
```

here is the full code

```
function addMarker(props){
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:props.coords,
            map:map,
            //icon:props.iconImage  
            });

            // Check for customicon
            if(props.iconImage){
                // Set icon image
                marker.setIcon(props.iconImage);
            }

            // Check content
            if(props.content){
                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content:props.content

                });

                marker.addListener('click', function(){
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            }

        }
```

I am guessing it is this way because I am using an API but I would like a better understanding on why it needs to be this way.

Comment: Maybe try to `console.log(google.maps)`, in chrome dev you'll find Marker and Infowindow are it's methods

Comment: I thought that was what I would find. But I did't understand why Marker and InfoWindow was capitalized like a class name in java is, while everything before it was not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd like to use Marker and InfoWindow as Java classes that would have been `import`ed inside of your file. Well there's no such thing as `import` in Javascript (actually there is, but currently, it doesn't exist in browser environments).

Anyway, in Javascript, everything is an object. You could think of Javascript objects as Maps in java : they are basically key-value structures.

Somewhere, inside the code of the Google Maps library you're using, an object called google is defined. It contains a key called maps, which in turn contains an object. This object in turn contains definitions for the google maps library, such as `Marker` and `InfoWindow`.

It actually could look like this :

```
var gooogle = {
  maps: {
    Marker: /* definition of Marker */,
    InfoWindow: /* definition of InfoWindow */,
    // ...
  }       
}
```

That's why you need that dot notation. You're actually accessing a sub-sub-key of the `google` object, that was declared by the library you imported.

Comment: Thanks, off topic but is what you just explained to me just JSON?

Comment: But why is only Marker capitalized?

Comment: I didn't get what you asked in your second comment. Marker is not the only one capitalized, InfoWindow is too (this is called camel case). As for the first one, no this is not JSON. JSON is a standardized format used to *serialize* javascript objects (this means : converting an internal object of a program into a string). So yeah, JSON and javascript object declarations kinda look the same but do not serve the same purpose. JSON is a format used to write actual javascript objects inside plain strings, which is useful if you want to save them to a file or send them via HTTP, for instance.

Comment: Ok got it. I know about camel case and you actually answered my question the first time. My brain was fried from a programming binge haha.